# Generating Hash or String via TouchID in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

I want to make an unique string or hash via Touch ID on iPhones in Swift. I search a lot about it but I didn't find a solution to make it.

Comment: You can't. All you can do with Touch ID is get a "yes" or "no" answer about whether the user touched the Touch ID sensor with a valid finger or not.

Comment: TouchID is just an authentication method. You can generate a UUID and store it in the keychain, requiring TouchID to access the item in the keychain. You can also request TouchID authentication before initially generating the UUID and storing it but there is nothing about the TouchID process itself that can generate an identifier.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you so much. How Can I generate an UUID? And How Can I get it inside of my app?

Comment: Use the NSUUID class. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you so much. I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can NOT do this.

you can use **universally unique identifier (UUID)** of an ios Device.

```
let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
```

or generate your own **unique** identifier using [irreversible algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Comment: That string will not be tied to a fingerprint which I'm guessing is what the OP wanted to do.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to create an App in iOS that when user input his fingerprint on Touch ID, then the App returns an unique hash or string as an a password or some secret key.  @Mojtabye

Comment: you can Not tie fingerprint to unique hash too much ! , because as i said before result is boolean only ! . `let toHash = email + isAuthenticated + UUID`.