# Implement fingerprint authentication on php mysql

Tags: php

I am using PHP login API which I need to be integrated with a fingerprint login page.
This means that the user doesn't need to type a password, he will put his fingerprint and if it's valid and recognized, then he will be able to login to this ios/android app. Is this possible? How can I do this?

I have app(ios/android) and php and mysql backend .  I have to implement fingerprint authentication How can i achieve this using PHP API and this functionality only for client side.
Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add a column for the fingerprint to your users table. In you app code, you should get some sort of unique id once you have the fingerprint.

First time they add their fingerprint, post to your API and add it to the users row.

Second time, call a different login endpoint passing the unique id, and fetch that way.

update - i just read apple only supply yes or no with touch id. i saw this question [Generating Hash or String via TouchID in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123092/generating-hash-or-string-via-touchid-in-swift) and it says the way to do it is to get the uuid

`let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString`

then you can say :

`let toHash = email + isAuthenticated + UUID`

Comment: Thanks for the reply... it's working for the android app but ios not creating same hash code every time.

Comment: It looks like because partial fingerprints etc. i have updated the answer